# Python check if Items are in list

Tags: python, list, loops

I am trying to iterate through two lists and check if items in list_1 are in list_2. If the item in list_1 is in list_2 I would like to print the item in list_2.  If the item is NOT in list_2 I would like print the item from list_1.  The below code accomplishes this partially but because I am performing two for loops I am getting duplicate values of list_1. Can you please direct me in a Pythonic way to accomplish?

```
list_1 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'Y', 'Z']
list_2 = ['Letter A',
          'Letter C',
          'Letter D',
          'Letter H',
          'Letter I',
          'Letter Z']

for i in list_1:
    for x in list_2:
        if i in x:
            print(x)
        else:
            print(i)
```

Current Output:

```
Letter A
A
A
A
A
A
B
B
B
B
B
B
C
Letter C
C
C
C
C
D
D
Letter D
D
D
D
Y
Y
Y
Y
Y
Y
Z
Z
Z
Z
Z
Letter Z
```

Desired Output:

```
Letter A
B
Letter C
Letter D
Y
Letter Z
```

Comment: How do you expect to get 6 lines of output when you're loops output approximately the lengths of the lists multiplied together?

Comment: I mean just B. The item in list_1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write:

```
for i in list_1:
    found = False
    for x in list_2:
        if i in x:
            found = True
            break
    if found:
        print(x)
    else:
        print(i)
```

The approach above ensure that you either print `x` or `i` and we only print one value per element in `list_1`.

You could also write (which is the same thing as above but makes use of the ability to add an `else` to a `for` loop):

```
for i in list_1:
    for x in list_2:
        if i in x:
            print(x)
            break
    else:
        print(i)
```

Comment: Excellent! Exactly what I was looking for. The second approach is what was trying to achieve. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in list_1:
    found = False
    for x in list_2:
        if i in x:
            found = True
            print(x)
    if found == False:
        print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Oneliner:

```
[print(i) for i in ["Letter {}".format(i) if "Letter {}".format(i) in list_2 else i for i in list_1]]
```

Outputs:

```
Letter A
B
Letter C
Letter D
Y
Letter Z
```

Answer (score -1):

```
for i in list_1:
    for x in list_2:
        if i not in x:
            continue
        else:
            print(x)
```

Answer (score -2):

```
for i in range(len(list_1)):
  if list_1[i] in list_2[i]:
    print(list_2[i])
  else:
    print(list_1[i])
```

Comment: Will fail dramatically since using the same index for both lists